# How to show a nested object as a super object in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

As it is stated [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref), I had to save reference objects inside of a nested key called 'item';

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  connections: [{
    kind: String,
    item: { type: ObjectId, refPath: 'connections.kind' }
  }]
});

var organizationSchema = new Schema({ name: String, kind: String });

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
var Organization = mongoose.model('Organization', organizationSchema);
```

In my DB, it is more like this:

```
var childSchema = new Schema({
    kind: String,
    item: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        refPath: 'children.kind'
    }
},{ _id : false, strict:false });

var schema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    kind: String,
    children: [childSchema]
},{
    strict: false
});
```

Now, it is a tree based folder structure model, and it can have either a Folder or a Leaf as child object.

I needed a recursive populate, so I find an answer on SO, it became like this;

```
var autoPopulateChildren = function(next) {
    this.populate({path:'children.item', select:'name id children'});
    next();
};

schema.pre('findOne', autoPopulateChildren)
    .pre('find', autoPopulateChildren)
```

Now, when I make a `find` query, I get this-like example;

```
{
  "name": "Some Folder",
  "children": [
    {
      "kind": "Leaf",
      "item": {
        "name": "First Level Leaf",
        "id": "5b61c85f25375fddf6048d3c"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "Folder",
      "item": {
        "name": "First Level Folder",
        "id": "5b61d844d77fb30b9537e5d1"
        "children": [
          {
            "kind": "Leaf",
            "item": {
              "name": "Second Level Leaf",
              "id": "5b61c85f25375fddf6048d3c"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "id": "5b61c85f25375fddf6048d3d"
}
```

But now, I need to get rid of 'kind' (don't show) and also I need to show 'item' object as a child (it should be `name` instead of `item:{name:'a'}`:

```
{
  "name": "Some Folder",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "First Level Leaf",
      "id": "5b61c85f25375fddf6048d3c"
    },
    {
      "name": "First Level Folder",
      "id": "5b61d844d77fb30b9537e5d1"
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Second Level Leaf",
          "id": "5b61c85f25375fddf6048d3c"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "id": "5b61c85f25375fddf6048d3d"
}
```

How can I do this on `autoPopulateChildren` function?